# Bigcommerce Stancil Theme product Description show on home page?

Tags: bigcommerce

Please help me we want to show product description on home page under top selling products,In bigcommerce stancil theme.
if any one have any solution for this.let us know.

Thanks

Comment: please provide store URL and mentions where you want to show products descriptions.

Comment: Thanks @Raj Kumar Bhardwaj fot quick reply here is the store url https://www.amazingdoors.us/ & i want to show top sellers products descriptions on home page in bigcommerce stancil theme

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solutions

open your storfront->themes and then edit the file in editing mode i hope you know this.

Now to go your component->Products->top.html and after  closed paste this code

```
 {{#if summary}} <p>{{{summary}}}</p>{{/if}}
```

after that, your file code will look like this

```
<h2 class="page-heading">{{lang 'products.top' }}</h2>

<ul class="productGrid productGrid--maxCol{{ columns }}" data-product-type="top_sellers">
    {{#each products}}
        <li class="product">
            {{>components/products/card theme_settings=../theme_settings customer=../customer}}
               {{#if summary}}
                  <p>{{{summary}}}</p>
                {{/if}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

same it and it will show front end something like this

http://vishu-rajs-store3.mybigcommerce.com/

preview code:  nkkdg75b5l

similarly, you can do this with featured, new and related

but if you want to show in all products at once go to your Components->Products->card.html and paste the summary code below the product title.

Thanks